# J-Link programmer in Windows 8 don't work

Tags: driver, flash, error, cortex-m3, windows

I use the J-Link programmer in Windows 8. A few days ago, my programmer hanged and the LEDs stayed silent, and I, with the help of the Internet, was again using the SAM-BA software to install the appropriate firmware for it.
Because of the problem with running SAM-BA on my laptop, I had to install it on my co-worker laptop.
This programmer works on my co-op laptop, but on my laptop, flash v4.7 detects it and runs the program on it, but it does not run after writing the code. shown below:

[image: code runed in jflash but dont working]

and with the click of the flash download, which puts the program on This is the message below:

[image: Error: Flash Download failed - "Cortex-M3"]

Error: Flash Download failed  -  "Cortex-M3"

The point here is that the program works on my co-worker's laptop, and with the same settings on my laptop I do the erase flash, but in the programming  flash, it dosesn't work. shown below:

[image]
I reinstalled Kell and j-Link software, but I did not.

my windows drivers are like this:

[image: windows drivers]

I wonder where the problem is? !!

Answer (score 2):

I found the way to fix it do this steps:

1- uninstall windows jlink driver like this:

[image: uninstall windows jlink driver]

2- uninstall jlink segger software, like this:

[image: uninstall jlink segger software]

3-install another segger jlink software linke [this version](https://www.segger.com/downloads/jlink/Setup_JLink_V510i.zip.sig).

4- you could program your code by setting jflash setting like this:

[image: jflash setting]

and you could do it too with keil like this:

[image: keil]

thank a lot.